# Keras evaluate give different result than history. Which one is accurate

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I am wokring on the classification of EEG data (time series) and i am getting different accuracy using evaluate function in keras and from history of iterations in keras.
I want to know which one is more accurate to consider.
 Here is my keras model

```
model=Sequential()
model.add(Conv1D(filters=60,kernel_size=5,strides=1,padding='same',input_shape=X_train.shape[1::]))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Conv1D(filters=40,kernel_size=5,strides=1,padding='same'))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Conv1D(filters=20,kernel_size=3,strides=1,padding='same'))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(50,activation='tanh'))
model.add(Dense(20,activation='tanh'))
model.add(Dense(2,activation='sigmoid'))
optimizer=optimizers.Adam(lr=0.0001)
model.compile(optimizer=optimizer,loss='binary_crossentropy',metrics=['accuracy'])
history=model.fit(X_train,y_train,batch_size=20,epochs=100,
          verbose=2,validation_split=0.3)
print('accuracy',np.average(np.array(history.history['val_acc'])))
model.evaluate(X_test,y_test)
```

The accuracy I got by using evaluate function is 0.448. And accuracy I got by using history by averaging the validation accuracy is 0.709.

Here is accuracy log of last 20 epochs

```
Epoch 81/100
 - 2s - loss: 0.3923 - acc: 0.8217 - val_loss: 0.5482 - val_acc: 0.7327
Epoch 82/100
 - 2s - loss: 0.3843 - acc: 0.8227 - val_loss: 0.5522 - val_acc: 0.7305
Epoch 83/100
 - 2s - loss: 0.3885 - acc: 0.8235 - val_loss: 0.5589 - val_acc: 0.7268
Epoch 84/100
 - 2s - loss: 0.4001 - acc: 0.8142 - val_loss: 0.5781 - val_acc: 0.7177
Epoch 85/100
 - 2s - loss: 0.3938 - acc: 0.8165 - val_loss: 0.5474 - val_acc: 0.7396
Epoch 86/100
 - 2s - loss: 0.3965 - acc: 0.8187 - val_loss: 0.5587 - val_acc: 0.7230
Epoch 87/100
 - 2s - loss: 0.3768 - acc: 0.8279 - val_loss: 0.5947 - val_acc: 0.7107
Epoch 88/100
 - 2s - loss: 0.3789 - acc: 0.8288 - val_loss: 0.5583 - val_acc: 0.7334
Epoch 89/100
 - 2s - loss: 0.3805 - acc: 0.8262 - val_loss: 0.5690 - val_acc: 0.7227
Epoch 90/100
 - 2s - loss: 0.3712 - acc: 0.8302 - val_loss: 0.5661 - val_acc: 0.7271
Epoch 91/100
 - 2s - loss: 0.3678 - acc: 0.8361 - val_loss: 0.5798 - val_acc: 0.7180
Epoch 92/100
 - 2s - loss: 0.3727 - acc: 0.8352 - val_loss: 0.5927 - val_acc: 0.7085
Epoch 93/100
 - 2s - loss: 0.3720 - acc: 0.8271 - val_loss: 0.5622 - val_acc: 0.7321
Epoch 94/100
 - 2s - loss: 0.3829 - acc: 0.8200 - val_loss: 0.5799 - val_acc: 0.7155
Epoch 95/100
 - 2s - loss: 0.3630 - acc: 0.8384 - val_loss: 0.5623 - val_acc: 0.7337
Epoch 96/100
 - 2s - loss: 0.3655 - acc: 0.8330 - val_loss: 0.5817 - val_acc: 0.7164
Epoch 97/100
 - 2s - loss: 0.3722 - acc: 0.8314 - val_loss: 0.5892 - val_acc: 0.7164
Epoch 98/100
 - 2s - loss: 0.3591 - acc: 0.8373 - val_loss: 0.5750 - val_acc: 0.7155
Epoch 99/100
 - 2s - loss: 0.3710 - acc: 0.8327 - val_loss: 0.5674 - val_acc: 0.7258
Epoch 100/100
 - 2s - loss: 0.3669 - acc: 0.8319 - val_loss: 0.5900 - val_acc: 0.7104
```

I am bit confused which one is more accurate. Figure shows validation accuracy and train accuracy
[image: Validation accuracy and train accuracy]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are correct - you are simply using a different data set each time.

You specify

```py
model.fit(X_train,y_train,batch_size=20,epochs=100,
          verbose=2,validation_split=0.3)
```

which means that 30% of the training data set is not used for training and set aside for validation (`validation_split=0.3`). This is the validation loss you see in the history.

However, during testing, you do this:

```py
model.evaluate(X_test,y_test)
```

which uses an entirely new data set `X_test`. Since you are getting significantly lower accuracies on this data set, it must be fundamentally different from your training set in some way, and your model fails to capture this variability.

Now, which accuracy reflects the "true" performance? Neither. Both. It depends on what `X_test` contains, in what way it is different from `X_train`, and what you want your model to be good at. But usually, you would report the model performance on *new* and *unseen* data, i.e., `X_test`.

Comment: oh, i see. i know this thing, but i made a stupid mistake. Just use an old script and did not check it thoroughly.